# Determine point where area between tangent and curve is minimal

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Given a certain function, how do we determine a point on the function $(a,f(a))$ where the area between its tangent at that point and the function is minimal?

For example, the function given is $f(x)=-x^2 + 4x + 5$ on the interval $(0,3)$.

Comment: Since the concavity of $-x^2+4x+5$ doesn't change (it is always concave down), the area bounded between the tangent and the function is zero. For this to work, you need a function which has an inflection point so that the concavity changes.

Comment: Removing the word "bounded" doesn't change anything. Do you mean the area between the function, the tangent, and $x = 0$ and $x = 3$?

Comment: yes that's what i meant

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Say that $a = 1$ and $f(x) = -x^2 + 4x + 5$. What would the area be?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** find the slope of the tangent line:

\begin{align}f(x)=-x^2 + 4x + 5, m=(f(x))'=-2x+4  \end{align}

**Step 2:** find the intercept and equation of the tangent line at $x=a$:\begin{align} -a^2+4a+5=(-2a+4)a+b, b=a^2+5,y=(-2a+4)x+a^2+5\end{align}

**Step 3:** find the area bounded by $f(x)$,the tangent line, $x=0,$ and $x=3$ :
\begin{align}S=\int_0^3 (((-2a+4)x+a^2+5)-(-x^2+4x+5)) dx=\int_0^3 (x-a)^2 dx=3(a-\frac{3}{2})^2+\frac{9}{4}\end{align}

**Conclusion:** when  $x=\frac{3}{2}, S$ is minimum.

[image]